# Ansible - Hide values loop account creation

Tags: loops, ansible

I try to create local account with a loop on ansible.

passwords are in group_vars vaulted

```yaml
- name: "Add users"
  user:
    name: "{{item.name}}"
    uid: "{{item.uid}}"
    password: "{{ item.name | string | password_hash('sha512') }}"
    group: toto
    update_password: always
    comment: toto
    shell: /bin/bash
    password_expire_max: 365
  loop:
    - { uid: 12000, name: 'toto', password: "{{ toto  | string | password_hash('sha512') }}" }
```

When i launch my playbook, password is printed in SHA in the loop

```
ok: [192.168.113.199] => (item={u'password': u' password in sha ', u'uid': 12000, u'name': u'toto'})
```

Does somebody know how hide the password ?
Thank's by advance

Comment: Add this `no_log: true` to the task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *When I launch my playbook, password is printed in SHA in the loop*

You may have a look into [Adding controls to loops](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#adding-controls-to-loops), [Limiting loop output with `label`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#limiting-loop-output-with-label) and use just additionally

```yaml
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.name }}"
```

This will limit the console output to the username key and value only. Also [Extended loop variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#extended-loop-variables) can provide advantage.

Answer (score 0):

When you're dealing with sensitive data, you can always use the "no_log: true" option for your task. This way the looped item will not show an output to console.

I see U888D has suggested using [Limiting loop output with label](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#limiting-loop-output-with-label), however, from that same page it is stated:

> This is for making console output more readable, not protecting
> sensitive data. If there is sensitive data in loop, set no_log: yes on
> the task to prevent disclosure.

For more more information about no_log you can see here: [Protecting sensitive data with no_log](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/logging.html).